# Where should I put a reusable method in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am new to Grails. I would like to create a reusable function that can calculate a percentage (0 - 100%) based on any 2 input values I specify. I would like this to be reusable across domains and controllers, but I am having a hard time figuring out where to put this function.

Here is my code:

```
def calcPercentComplete(hoursComp, hoursReq) {
  def dividedVal = hoursComp/hoursReq
  def Integer result = dividedVal * 100

  // results will have a min and max range of 0 - 100.
  switch(result){
    case{result > 100}:
      result = 100
      break

    case {result <= 0}:
      result =  0
      break

    default: return result
  }

}
```

Does anyone have advice on best practices for implementing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you write a class (say called `TimeUtils.groovy`) and put it in `src/groovy/utils`

Then add something that does this as a static method:

```
package utils

class TimeUtils {
  static Integer calcPercentComplete(hoursComp, hoursReq) {
    Integer result = ( hoursComp / hoursReq ) * 100.0
    result < 0 ? 0 : result > 100 ? 100 : result
  }
}
```

You should then be able to call:

```
def perc = utils.TimeUtils.calcPercentComplete( 8, 24 )
```

From anywhere in your code

Comment: Thanks for the response. This looks really elegant. I will try it out and let you know how it works.

Comment: @Abbazaba glad to help!  Have fun!